# Timing a process in C using clock(), time(), clock_gettimes() and the rdtsc() intrinsic returning confusing values

Tags: c, linux, timing

I'm timing a bit of C code and comparing the output between `times()` `clock()` and `clock_gettime()` and using the `rdtsc` intrinsic to calculate the number of clock cycles elapsed.

Noticing that clock always gives me a value that is .02 seconds greater than what time() returns (after summing user + system).

When I run clock at the beginning of the program it already shows ~2k CLOCKS_PER_SECOND instead of 0 as shown in the output below.

OS is `Ubuntu 20.04LTS`
Processor speed is `3.50 GHz`

Example outputs
The first two lines are printed at the begging of the program, last two at the end.

```
clock() returns 2593 clocks-per sec (0.00 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00
clock() returns 8616 clocks-per sec (0.01 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00

clock() returns 2448 clocks-per sec (0.00 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00
clock() returns 8403 clocks-per sec (0.01 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00

clock() returns 2541 clocks-per sec (0.00 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00
clock() returns 5915366 clocks-per sec (5.92 secs)
times() yields: user CPU: 5.49; system CPU: 0.41
```

Added rdtsc and clock_gettimes() to this comparison

```
clock() returns 2341 clocks-per sec (0.00 secs)
     times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00
    resolution:          0.000000001
    clockTtime:     143071.541191700
     clock() returns 11560076 clocks-per sec (11.56 secs)
     times() yields: user CPU: 10.77; system CPU: 0.78
    resolution:          0.000000001
    clockTtime:     143083.561227466
RTDSC COUNTER: 41973477274 CPU cycles

clock() returns 2325 clocks-per sec (0.00 secs)
     times() yields: user CPU: 0.00; system CPU: 0.00
    resolution:          0.000000001
    clockTtime:     143570.023404324
     clock() returns 12039250 clocks-per sec (12.04 secs)
     times() yields: user CPU: 11.00; system CPU: 1.03
    resolution:          0.000000001
    clockTtime:     143583.562080061
RTDSC COUNTER: 47277160370 CPU cycles
```

Key takeaways the timings are off by .02 - .01 seconds even though I would expect the time returned by clock() to have the lowest value since it's measured before times() or clock_gettimes().

For one of the outputs above
clock returns: 11.56 seconds
times returns: 11.55 seconds
clock_gettime() returns: 12.020035766
rdtsc returns 41973477274 cycles which for a computer with a 3.5GHzz processor = 11.9924220783 seconds and rdtsc is measured first and last so it should have the highest value as it includes the cost of the clock(), time(), and clock_gettime() calls as well.

relevant code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

void timeAlgorithm(const char* msg) {
        // Three ways to get system process times - times(), clock(), clock_gettime()
        struct tms t;
        struct timespec tp;
        static struct timespec res;
        clock_t clockTime;
        static long clockTicks = 0;
        // Fetch clock ticks on first call
        if (clockTicks == 0) {
                clockTicks = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
                if (clockTicks == -1) {
                        perror("Error getting sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) value program will now exit");
                        return exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        clockTime = clock();
        if (clockTime == -1) {
                perror("Error getting process clock time using clock(), Program will now exit");
                return exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\t clock() returns %ld clocks-per sec (%.2f secs)\n",
                        (long)clockTime, (double) clockTime / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        if (times(&t) == -1) {
                perror("The time call failed, this program will now exit.");
                return exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\t times() yields: user CPU: %.2f; system CPU: %.2f\n",
                        (double) t.tms_utime / clockTicks,
                        (double) t.tms_stime / clockTicks);

        if (!res.tv_sec) {
                if (clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res) == -1) {
                        perror("clock_getres() call failed, this program will now exit");
                        return exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }

        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp) == -1) {
                perror("clocl_gettime() call failed, this program will now exit.");
                return exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\tresolution: %10jd.%09ld\n",
                        (intmax_t)res.tv_sec, res.tv_nsec);

        printf("\tclockTtime: %10jd.%09ld\n",
                        (intmax_t)tp.tv_sec, tp.tv_nsec);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("CLOCKS_PER_SEC=%ld\tsysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)=%ld\n\n",
                        (long)CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK));
        uint64_t start = __rdtsc();
        timeAlgorithm("At program start");
        // 1 less than 4 gigs because 2^32 - 1 is the max value for a uint32_t and 2^32 = 4gb 
        // Not 2 or 4 gigs right now so I can debug faster
        uint32_t TWOGIGS = (uint32_t)(2147483648 / 1) - 1;
        // Set seed for random
        srandom(time(NULL));
        uint32_t TWOGIGSOFLONGS = (uint32_t)(TWOGIGS / sizeof(long));
        long* unsortedData = malloc(sizeof(long) * TWOGIGSOFLONGS);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TWOGIGSOFLONGS; ++i) {
                unsortedData[i] = random();
                //printf("%d\t%ld\n", i, unsortedData[i]);
        }
        timeAlgorithm("At program end");
        uint64_t end = __rdtsc();
        printf("RTDSC COUNTER: %lu CPU cycles\n", end - start);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

This difference shouldn't matter in practice, I could just chose to use one of these functions and move on but I'm curious if anyone knows why all these values are different in this strange way.

If clock() had a value that was lower than times() which was lower than clock_gettimes() which was lower than __rdtsc() it would make sense as that's the order in which these time are measured but that's not the case and is confusing.

Comment: *at the beginning of the program it already shows ~2k CLOCKS_PER_SECOND instead of 0*. That's totally unsurprising. Unless you are writing your own C-runtime (crt) and adding the timing into that then by the time your code runs the crt startup code has already done a fair bit.

Comment: @kaylum I see, is it because clock measures time taken by the process since it started until I call clock? In a multithreaded process will this include time taken by child process that have to be waited?

Comment: @NateEldredge added the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else comes across this I came across this paper and am using this to time my code https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf

Comment: New link: https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/How%20to%20Benchmark%20Code%20Execution%20Times%20on%20Intel%20IA-32%20and%20IA-64%20Instruction%20Set%20Architectures%20-%20September%2C%202010%20(324264-001).pdf